# How to pass TextInput value from one screen to another in react native?

Tags: react-native

I know this question is already asked but i didn't find any proper solution.  So here is my question, i want to pass TextInput value to another screen on submit button.So, please tell me How to pass the value and display on another screen. I am new in react native development.

Comment: What you're really asking is "how do I pass state around?" and there are multiple answers for this. Try reading about state management in react, and maybe a library like Redux or Mobx.

Comment: How do you navigate to the other screen?
Do you use StackNavigator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the top of your component you want to declare your state.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {text: ""};
```

Then you want to save whatever text is in your TextInput to that state.

```
<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})} />
```

Then you would want to pass that state to the other component you would need it in.

Add this to the onPress of your submit button:

```
onPress={() => navigate('OtherComponent',  { text: this.state.text} )}
```

Then in your "OtherComponent" you can access the state like this:

`this.props.navigation.state.params.text`

This is assuming that you are using react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your component you want to declare your state.

class App extends Component {
  state = {text: ""};
Then you want to save whatever text is in your TextInput to that state.

this.setState({text})} />

Then you would want to pass that state to the other component you would need it in.

Add this to the onPress of your submit button:

onPress={() =>   this.props.navigation.navigate('OtherComponent', { text: this.state.text} );
Then in your "OtherComponent" you can access the state like this:

this.props.navigation.state.params.text

This is assuming that you are using react-navigation.