# How to pass a TextInput value to another screen without using a button in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When a user enters their name via a `TextInput` component on a screen, I want their name to display on another screen when I navigate there, without having to use a `Button` to pass it across, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm using the `onChangeText` prop to capture the current state of the `TextInput`.

**AccountScreen** - where the input is taken

```jsx
const AccountScreen = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Name</Text>
        <TextInput
          value={name}
          onChangeText={(theName) => setName(theName)}
          placeholder={'Enter your name'}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default AccountScreen;
```

**BalanceScreen** - where I want the text to be displayed

```jsx
const BalanceScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.heading, { flex: 1 }]}>Account name: NAME TO DISPLAY HERE</Text>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Balance</Text>
        <Text style={styles.balanceAmount}>£1,234</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default BalanceScreen;
```

**App.js**

```jsx
import AccountScreen from './screens/AccountScreen';
import BalanceScreen from './screens/BalanceScreen';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const ScreenTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Balance"
      activeColor="#e91e63"
      //labelStyle={{ fontSize: 12 }}
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Balance"
        component={BalanceScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Balance',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="wallet-outline"
              color={color}
              size={26}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Account"
        component={AccountScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Account',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ScreenTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Most of the [examples](https://snack.expo.io/@aboutreact/react-native-pass-value-from-one-screen-to-another-using-react-navigation?session_id=snack-session-BkdY7MFhm) I've come across are using the `onPress` prop of `Button`, which I don't want to use.

I've tried using the navigate techniques from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051607/how-to-pass-textinput-value-from-one-screen-to-another-in-react-native), but wasn't successful.

I've also tried using the techniques from [this article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-send-state-of-current-component-as-a-parameter-to-another-external-method-using-react). In the **AccountScreen**, I tried adding a new function `const handleChange = () => setstate({name})` and changed the `onChangeText` property to `onChangeText={(theName) => setName(theName), () => handleChange}` and in the **BalanceScreen** I changed `<Text style={[styles.heading, { flex: 1 }]}>Account name: {useState}</Text>`, but this didn't work either and it makes the `TextInput` box inactive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to share data between components, without passing it around via props. At this point it makes sense to introduce a concept for managing your state across components (you probably need the user name and further data in several components). I'd suggest to introduce [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). It's the most widely adopted method of handling data in React (also React Native) and maintained by Facebook.

In a nutshell Redux is a global state object that's the single source of truth in your application. This global state is received as props into your React Native components. 'Any time a piece of data is changed in the Redux state (e.g. your username), the entire application receives the new data as props. You can also combine Redux with further concepts for persisting your user data and app state even after the app's been closed via [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

There are tons of articles and tutorials out there, to put you into the right direction, I've added some code snippets to explain the main building blocks:

1. **Global Store**

You might going to have a store.js file which collects all your reducers and represents to global store

```ts
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer'

const store = createStore(userReducer)

export default store
```

2. **Provider**

You might going to provide that global store to your application within the App.js file

```ts
import store from './src/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

export default class App extends React.Component {
render (){
    return (
    <Provider store = { store }>
        <RootNavigator />
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

3. **Reducer**

You might create at least one "Reducer" that provides a user object for the global state

```ts
const defaultUserName = "Peter Pan"

const filterReducer = (state = {userName : defaultUserName}, action:any) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_USERNAM:
        
            return {
                userName: action.userName
            }

        case GET_USERNAME:
            return {
                userName: state.userName
            }
    }
}
```

4. **Actions**

You might define actions to manipulate and access the data in your store

```ts
export const GET_USERNAME = 'GET_USERNAME'
export const SET_USERNAME = 'SET_USERNAME'

export function getUserName () {
    return {
        type: GET_USERNAME
    }
}

export function updateFilterQuery () {
    return {
        type: SET_USERNAME
    }   
}
```

5. **Connect and Dispatch**

With the connect function you might access data from the Redux state as props in your components and also create dispatch functions that interact with reducers using action. The sample code stores the username globally. You can adopt this for your Balance Screen, when using a "getter" instead:

```ts
class AccountScreen extends React.Component<any, { userName: string }>  {

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userName : ""
        }
    }

    setUserName(userName:string) {
        this.props.setUserName(userName)
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.heading}>Name</Text>
                    <TextInput
                    value={name}
                    onChangeText={(theName) => this.setUserName(theName)}
                    placeholder={'Enter your name'}
                    />
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => {
    return {
        setUserName: () => dispatch(setUserName())
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => {
    return {
    userName: state.userReducer.userName
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AccountScreen)
```

I hope this helps. It's not a quick fix, but it's worth investing the time. It's easy to be introduced now and will help with scaling your app smoothly. However, if you're searching for a quick and dirty solution you can also just save the username in a global variable and import it into your Balance Screen ;)